# How to calculate data using if/elif/else and minimum value in columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have the DataFrame:

```
a = [{'name': 'A', 'col_1': 5, 'col_2': 3, 'col_3': 1.5},
     {'name': 'B', 'col_1': 4, 'col_2': 2.5, 'col_3': None},
     {'name': 'C', 'col_1': 8, 'col_2': None, 'col_3': None},
     {'name': 'D', 'col_1': 7, 'col_2': 9, 'col_3': None}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].fillna(0)
df['col_2'] = df['col_2'].fillna(0)
df['col_3'] = df['col_3'].fillna(0)
print(df)
```

I'm trying to calculate the values for the `df['color_4']` column, and I'm trying to do it in one line of code. But maybe it is impossible.

The calculation logic is as follows, and it works for `df['name'] == 'A' and 'B'`, but not for `df['name'] == 'C'` and should be supplemented

```
df['col_4'] = [i if i != 0 else x - (x * 0.75) for i, x, y in zip(df['col_3'], df['col_2'], df['col_1'])]
```

It is necessary to continue the calculation, if the value is in the `df['col_3'] and df['col_2'] == 0`, then `y - (y * 0.75)` -> `df['col_1']`

In the case of `df['name'] == 'D'`, it is first necessary to compare the values in the columns `df['col_1'] and df['col_2']` and choose the **minimum** value

I need the next result:

[image]

Comment: Probably just a typo, but do you mean `color_1` or `col_1`?

Comment: @JohnGordon, hi, yes, thanks for the correction. I have already corrected.


calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use Pandas operations, but I let it in the style you want :

```py
df['col_4'] = [t[0] if t[0]>0 else 
               (min(t[1], t[2]) - (min(t[1], t[2]) * 0.75) if bool(t[1]) else t[2]-0.75*t[2]) 
               for t in zip(df['col_3'], df['col_2'], df['col_1'])]
```

**Complete script for checking**

```py
import pandas as pd

a = [{'name': 'A', 'col_1': 5, 'col_2': 3, 'col_3': 1.5},
     {'name': 'B', 'col_1': 4, 'col_2': 2.5, 'col_3': None},
     {'name': 'C', 'col_1': 8, 'col_2': None, 'col_3': None},
     {'name': 'D', 'col_1': 7, 'col_2': 9, 'col_3': None}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].fillna(0)
df['col_2'] = df['col_2'].fillna(0)
df['col_3'] = df['col_3'].fillna(0)

df['col_4'] = [t[0] if t[0]>0 else 
               (min(t[1], t[2]) - (min(t[1], t[2]) * 0.75) if bool(t[1]) else t[2]-0.75*t[2]) 
               for t in zip(df['col_3'], df['col_2'], df['col_1'])]

print(df)
```

**Result**

```
  name  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
0    A      5    3.0    1.5  1.500
1    B      4    2.5    0.0  0.625
2    C      8    0.0    0.0  2.000
3    D      7    9.0    0.0  1.750
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify you logic to:

- get the min of col_1/col_2
- if col_3 is 0, use 0.25 * that min value
- else use col_3

```
df['col_4'] = np.where(df['col_3'].eq(0),
                       df[['col_1', 'col_2']].min(axis=1).mul(0.25),
                       df['col_3'])
```

Output:

```
  name  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
0    A      5    3.0    1.5  1.500
1    B      4    2.5    0.0  0.625
2    C      8    0.0    0.0  0.000
3    D      7    9.0    0.0  1.750
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as I wrote, if the value is in the `df['col_3'] ==0` and `df['col_2'] == 0` for the calculation, the value is taken from the `df['col_1']` column. In this case, I'm talking about `df['name'] == 'C'` where the value should be `2` after the calculation, but when using your line when, the minimum value is selected, and it is equal to `0`, respectively, and the result is `0`, which does not give the desired result. But for the case `df['name'] == 'D'` it works. That's why I tried to use `if else`

Comment: So we can complete this way using this line of code, `df['col_4'] = [i if i != 0 else k * 0.25 for i, k in zip(df['col_4'], df['col_1'])]` , and finally we get needed result